# Cannot change element.style.height value with loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

The code only changes the element's height value at the end of the loop, which means no animation :,(

The code is like following:

```
 function heightenElement(id,interval,step,height,unit) {
 y = 0;


function loop() {
 y = y + step;
 thing = y + unit;
  console.log(y);
    if (y < height) {
          document.getElementById(id).style.height = thing;
      setTimeout(loop(),interval);
    }
  }
    loop();
 }
```

An answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` accepts a function as a parameter - if you put a function *call* in there, the function will be executed immediately. Simply pass the function name instead:

```js
function heightenElement(id, interval, step, height, unit) {
  let y = 0;
  function loop() {
    y = y + step;
    thing = y + unit;
    console.log(y);
    if (y < height) {
      document.getElementById(id).style.height = thing;
      setTimeout(loop, interval);
    }
  }
  loop();
}

heightenElement('div', 500, 10, 100, 'px');
```

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: `setInterval` isn't the function you used in your code. :)

Comment: ahaha that's true :) Anyways, thanks man, it's really appreciated